# How to add notes to text that appear highlighted in compiled pdf?

Tags: notes

I am going to submit my major revision and in compiled pdf file I have added notes to text that have been edited or where new text is inserted, so that reviewer can easily identify corrections made by me. But if I further edit my source file then the notes in pdf would be useless and I have to again repeat the process of inserting notes to text. The following snapshot describes what actually I do

[image]

Is it possible to add such type of notes to text directly in the latex document , such that those notes can be activated or inactivated as per requirement ? I am aware of `todonotes` but not appropriate for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pdfcomment` package is what you are looking for. To disable the annotations, use the option `final`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[%
%   final%
]{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[color=yellow]{New version of text, you want to have in the pdf}{Comment or old text or whatever}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And how we can inactivate these notes ? Do we have to manually delete those lengthy commands  ?

Comment: @IgotiT final option, as I wrote in the answer

Comment: Why my WinEdt is asking for file datetime2.sty ?

Comment: @IgotiT the package `pdfcomment` requires it. see documentation: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfcomment/doc/pdfcomment.pdf